# Count the number of duplicates in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array contacting following words

```
(“hello”, “apple”, “hello”, “hello”, “apple”, “orange”, “cake”)
```

`Result here should be 5`

Can you please tell me if there is a library function in `PHP` that I can use to count how many duplicate words are present in my array? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all for the detaied information. they all were very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array(“hello”, “apple”, “hello”, “hello”, “apple”, “orange”, “cake”);
$unique_elements = array_unique($array);
$totalUniqueElements = count($unique_elements); 
echo $totalUniqueElements; 
//Output 5

Hope this will help you.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can combine [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) with [`count()`](http://php.net/count):

```
$number_of_duplicates = count($words) - count(array_unique($words));
```

**Note:** PHP has over a hundred [Array Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). Learning them will make you a [better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 3):

Check `array_count_values` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

```
<?php
var_dump(array_count_values($words));

Output:
Array(
    [hello] => 3,
    [apple] => 2,
    [orange] => 1,
    [cake] => 1
)
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question directly, it is an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$count1 = count($array);
$count2 = count(array_unique($array));
echo $count1 - $count2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$org = count($array);
$unique = count(array_unique($array));
$duplicates = $org - $unique
```